# PHP - Reading ftp text files and extract required data

Tags: php, regex, text, ftp, extract

This is my first php script. I actually code in vb.net.. I am making this licensing system for .net applications. This licensing system has a manager which the admin can easily control and view. Also Iam making a class library to login and register for the same. I have succeeded in doing so using only vb.net code but as the credentials need to be stored inside the application there always is a threat. Using php this problem can be overcomed somewhat :tongue: . So I decided to make the login + register system using this kinda php scripts. I am using a only admin read,write text file instead of a mysql database ( Easily maneagable for all hosting services ). So, I have come up with this following piece of code and I need some help in the confirming the login part.
The text file is like this :

username password hwid lastdate membershiptype

All separated by 'space' and one account per line.
I hope I have given enough information, If extra information is needed, I will give it.

```
<?php
$user = addslashes($_GET['username']);
$pass = addslashes($_GET['password']);

  $username = "theusername";  
  $password = "thepassword";  
  $url = "mywebsite.com/file.txt";
  $hostname= "ftp://$username:$password@$url";  
  $contents = file_get_contents($hostname); 
// That gives me the txt file which can only be read and written by the admin
if (strpos($contents,$user) !== false) {
   // Need code here to check if the adjacent word and the $pass are same to establish a successfull login
} else {
 echo "Username does not exist, please register"
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about your question?

Comment: Whitespace and paragraphs are your friend.

Comment: He wants to traverse the file and get the values of each line to compare the info.

Comment: Also, what if one person's username is another person's password?  `strpos` would return a non-false value, but still not "exist".

Comment: jedwards Hmm I didn't really think about that.. How to use that only one the first words of a line for evey line ?. I want to get the password which is a 'space' away from the username. Can regex be used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this, hope it helps:

file.txt would need tobe in this format, values seperated by `:`, spaces are not a good way to seperate values.

```
username:password:hwid:lastdate:membershiptype
```

The PHP bit:

```
<?php
$user = $_GET['username'];
$pass = $_GET['password'];

if(check_auth(get_auth(),$user,$pass)==true){
    echo 'Yes';
}else{
    echo 'No';
}

/**
 * This function will grab the text file and create a user array
 * 
 * @return array(0=>username,1=>password)
 */
function get_auth(){
    $username = "theusername";
    $password = "thepassword";
    $url = "mywebsite.com/file.txt";
    $location = "ftp://$username:$password@$url";

    $users = file($location);
    function split_auth(&$value){
        $value = explode(':',$value);
    }
    array_walk($users,'split_auth');
    return $users;
}

/**
 * This Function will check the username and password
 *  against the users array
 *
 * @param array $users
 * @param string $username
 * @param string $password
 * @return bool (true|false)
 */
function check_auth($users,$username,$password){
    foreach($users as $user){
        if($user[0]==$username && $user[1]==$password){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
?>
```

Comment: So this will work ?  username:password:hwid:lastdate:membershiptype

Comment: yes if you change `username password hwid lastdate membershiptype` to `username:password:hwid:lastdate:membershiptype`